# CSS and Images Not Working When Deployed on Vercel

Tags: node.js, express, static, web-deployment, vercel

I have created a newsletter app with Mailchimp API and wanted to deploy it to vercel. I did get the html and js working but, for some reason my css is not working.

This is the code on my vercel.json

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "./index.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "/"
        }
    ]
}
```

I added this line of code on my index.js

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

these are how my files are placed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWAog.png)

This is how my website is rendering locally:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8B2d.png)

and this is how my website is rendering on vercel:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEADj.png)

I am guessing there is some error in finding the path to the files, I did try to change them but, it did not work. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Turns out all I had to do was this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public/"));
```

and my website started rendering all the images and css.